# How do I make a comment form appear and work correctly in my homepage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, erb, instance-variables

I have a Post model, and a Comment model that belongs to Post. I was able to display the Post in the home view corresponding to the home controller and home action and the User/show view. Thus, in the home and user views, the posts are listed in order of creation time. I was also able to have a post form in both the user and home views.

The problem arises when I try to display a comment form underneath each displayed Post in the home and user views. The home controller/ home action already has a variable @post for the new post form displayed, making it hard to initiate another post instance variable for the comment to be created . The comment form should be underneath the corresponding article, leading to the creation of a comment for that article.

How do I implement this in the home view? How do I initiate the Post and comment variables needed to handle the comment form?

Here is my home view: app/views/home/home.html.erb:

```
<% if logged_in? %>
<div class="row">
<aside class="col-md-4">
  <section class="user_info">
    <%= render 'shared/user_info' %>
  </section>
  <hr/>
  <br/>
  <section class="stats">
    <%= render 'shared/stats' %>
  </section>
  <section class="post_form">
<%= render 'shared/post_form' %>
</section>
</aside>
<div class="col-md-8">
<h3>Post Feed</h3>
<%= render 'shared/feed' %>
</div>
</div>
<% else %>
<div class="center jumbotron">
<h1>Welcome to the Unstarv website</h1>
<h2>
Please sign up now to use this site
<%= link_to "Sign Up",  signup_path =%> 
now.
</h2>
<%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path, class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
</div>
<%= link_to image_tag("rails.png", alt: "unstarv logo"),
        '#' %>
        <% end %>
```

And here is my home controller:

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
def home
  if logged_in?
 @post  = current_user.posts.build
 @feed_items = current_user.feed.paginate(page: params[:page])  
end
end
def about
end
def privacy
end
def terms
end
end
```

And here is my Post model, the relevant part:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
has_many :comments
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

The relevant part of my User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
attr_accessor :remember_token
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
has_many :comments
has_many :active_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                              foreign_key: "follower_id",
                              dependent:   :destroy
has_many :passive_relationships, class_name:  "Relationship",
                               foreign_key: "followed_id",
                               dependent:   :destroy
has_many :following, through: :active_relationships, source: :followed  
has_many :followers, through: :passive_relationships, source: :follower
validates :username,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
                has_secure_password
                validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_blank: true



def feed
following_ids = "SELECT followed_id FROM relationships
                 WHERE  follower_id = :user_id"
Post.where("user_id IN (#{following_ids})
                 OR user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
end
end
```

And here is my Comment model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :post
belongs_to :user
default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }  
end
```

And here is the post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]
def index
@posts = Post.all
end
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @comment = Comment.new
  @comment.post_id = @post.id
  @comments = @post.comments.all
end
def new
   @post = Post.new
end
def create
@post = current_user.posts.build(post_params)
if @post.save
  flash[:success] = "Post created!"
  redirect_to root_url
else
  @feed_items = []
  render 'home/home'
 end
 end
 def edit
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 end
  def update
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.update(post_params)
 flash.notice = "Post '#{@post.title}' Updated!"
 render 'home/home  '
end

 def update
 @post = Post.find(params[:id])
 @post.update(post_params)
 flash.notice = "Post '#{@post.title}' Updated!"
 redirect_to root_url
end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def post_params
  params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body, :picture)
end
end
```

Here is my app/views/post/_post.html.erb file,

```
 <li id="post-<%= post.id %>">
 <span class="user"><%= link_to post.user.username, post.user %></span>
 <span class="content">
 <%= post.title %>
 <%= post.body %>
 <%= image_tag post.picture.url if post.picture? %>
 </span>
 <span class="timestamp">
 Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago.
 <% if current_user?(post.user) %>
  <%= link_to "delete", post, method: :delete,
                                   data: { confirm: "You sure?" } %>
 <% end %>
 </span>
 <section>
 <h2>Your Comments here</h2>
 <h3>Post a Comment</h3>
 <h3>Post a Comment</h3>
 <%= render 'shared/comment_form' %>
 <% post.comments.all.each do |comment| %>
 <h4><small>Comment by</small> <%= comment.post.user.username %></h4> 
 <p class="comment"><%= comment.body %></p>
 <p><small>Posted <%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now,     comment.created_at) %> ago</small></p>
 <br/>
 <%end%>
 </li>
```

And here is my app/views/shared/comment_form_html.erb , which seems to be part of the problem as the instance variables are not correctly initialized:

```
<%= form_for [ @post1, @comment] do |f| %>
<p>
<%= f.label :body, "Your Comment" %><br/>
<%= f.text_area :body %>
</p>
<p>
<%= f.submit 'Submit' .  method="post", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

And finally here is my trace:

```
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:423:in `form_for'
app/views/shared/_comment_form.html.erb:1:in      `_app_views_shared__comment_form_html_erb__972919349_34226064'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:306:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:279:in `block in render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8)lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:38:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:278:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:47:in `render_partial'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/helpers/rendering_helper.rb:35:in `render'
app/views/posts/_post.html.erb:22:in `_app_views_posts__post_html_erb__365860364_28803540'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.1.8) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:161:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:339:in `instrument'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:399:in `block in collection_with_template'
actionview (4.1.8) lib/action_view/renderer/partial_renderer.rb:395:in `map'
```

Thanks a lot for your help !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `_post.html.erb`, change `<%= render 'shared/comment_form' %>` with `render 'shared/comment_form', post: post`

and then in `_comment_form_html.erb`, change `[@post1, @comment]` with `[post, @comment]`

**EDIT**

Also you need to add the following line to `HomeController#home`

```
@comment = Comment.new
```

**EDIT**

The issue/question is how you can generate an instance to be used in each comments form, right?

Since you are iterating each post `<%= render 'shared/feed' %>`, you already have an **post instance**, you are accessing this instance in `app/views/post/_post.html.erb`, the instance name is `post`.

When you try to render `comment_form`, you can pass parameters to the `render` method, you can send a parameter called `locals` or just send the paremeter as `name=value` that is a shorcut.

If you render `comment_form` sending the current `post` then you can generate the form based on that post.

since now you have access to `post` into `shared/_comment_form.html.erb`, the current issue is how generate a `comment`  instance, one way is to instance comment in each controller action where you want to show the feed (a bad option if it is used in multiple locations) and is what I said in the comment (my bad). I think the best option is change `[@post1, @comment]` (your original solution) with `[post, post.comments.build]`

How it will work? Since you already have access to `post` then you can just create an empty comment for that `post`  in the view

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others :)

Comment: Aguardientico, it is still not working. I get an ArgumentError in Home#home. Apparently, I get the error that First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty, which is post argument in form in this case.

Comment: You are right @JaimeGómez I will try to update the answer later.

Comment: @MoussaSarr: In your home controller you are not creating `@comment`, so I think it is the issue. Updating the answer

Comment: @Auguardientico , that s part of my problem and question. How do I create and initialize that specific instance variable in way that it links to the specific and appropriate post displayed in the home ?

Comment: @MoussaSarr I've added an explanation, please give a look to the last edit

Comment: @Aguardientico, Thanks the comment form works fine. Now I have trouble viewing the comments underneath the Post in the home and user pages. Here is the  question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929008/how-do-i-make-sure-each-post-in-the-post-feed-shown-in-the-home-page-has-all-its